# Build sandboxing disabled due to nsjail error (ninja failed with: exit status 1)

Tags: android, linux, android-source

I am trying to build AOSP.These were the following steps:

```
repo sync
make clobber
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_marlin_userdebug
m
```

When I execute the `lunch`, I get this in the console:

```
Build sandboxing disabled due to nsjail error.
============================================
```

after I excute `m`, i got an error: `ninja failed with: exit status 1`

then I found the log in soong.log:

```
2021/12/01 13:38:23.444890 build/soong/ui/build/build.go:165: Total RAM: 62.7GB
2021/12/01 13:38:26.100626 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:123: [prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/nsjail -H android-build -e -u nobody -g nobody -R / -B /tmp -B /home/chenmengshui/aosp -B /home/chenmengshui/aosp/out --disable_clone_newcgroup -- /bin/bash -c if [ $(hostname) == "android-build" ]; then echo "Android" "Success"; else echo Failure; fi]
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109367 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:130: Build sandboxing disabled due to nsjail error.
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109398 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Mode: STANDALONE_ONCE
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109412 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Jail parameters: hostname:'android-build', chroot:'', process:'/bin/bash', bind:[::]:0, max_conns:0, max_conns_per_ip:0, time_limit:0, personality:0, daemonize:false, clone_newnet:true, clone_newuser:true, clone_newns:true, clone_newpid:true, clone_newipc:true, clone_newuts:true, clone_newcgroup:false, clone_newtime:false, keep_caps:false, disable_no_new_privs:false, max_cpus:0
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109420 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Mount: '/' flags:MS_RDONLY type:'tmpfs' options:'' dir:true
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109428 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Mount: '/' -> '/' flags:MS_RDONLY|MS_BIND|MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE type:'' options:'' dir:true
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109436 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Mount: '/tmp' -> '/tmp' flags:MS_BIND|MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE type:'' options:'' dir:true
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109443 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Mount: '/home/chenmengshui/aosp' -> '/home/chenmengshui/aosp' flags:MS_BIND|MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE type:'' options:'' dir:true
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109450 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Mount: '/home/chenmengshui/aosp/out' -> '/home/chenmengshui/aosp/out' flags:MS_BIND|MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE type:'' options:'' dir:true
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109457 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Mount: '/proc' flags:MS_RDONLY type:'proc' options:'' dir:true
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109464 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Uid map: inside_uid:99 outside_uid:994 count:1 newuidmap:false
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109474 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [I][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800] Gid map: inside_gid:99 outside_gid:990 count:1 newgidmap:false
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109483 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [W][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800][18452] pid_t subproc::runChild(nsjconf_t *, int, int, int, int)():471 clone(flags=CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWUTS|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWUSER|CLONE_NEWPID|CLONE_NEWNET) failed: Invalid argument
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109490 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:133: [E][2021-12-01T13:38:26+0800][18452] int nsjail::standaloneMode(nsjconf_t *)():272 Couldn't launch the child process
2021/12/01 13:38:26.109507 build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go:139: nsjail failed with exit status 255
```

This line points to the source of the problem

```
pid_t subproc::runChild(nsjconf_t *, int, int, int, int)():471 clone(flags=CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWUTS|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWUSER|CLONE_NEWPID|CLONE_NEWNET) failed: Invalid argument
```

And I found it in the source file: https://github.com/google/nsjail/blob/master/subproc.cc

```
pid_t runChild(nsjconf_t* nsjconf, int netfd, int fd_in, int fd_out, int fd_err) {
    if (!net::limitConns(nsjconf, netfd)) {
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned long flags = 0UL;
    flags |= (nsjconf->clone_newnet ? CLONE_NEWNET : 0);
    flags |= (nsjconf->clone_newuser ? CLONE_NEWUSER : 0);
    flags |= (nsjconf->clone_newns ? CLONE_NEWNS : 0);
    flags |= (nsjconf->clone_newpid ? CLONE_NEWPID : 0);
    flags |= (nsjconf->clone_newipc ? CLONE_NEWIPC : 0);
    flags |= (nsjconf->clone_newuts ? CLONE_NEWUTS : 0);
    flags |= (nsjconf->clone_newcgroup ? CLONE_NEWCGROUP : 0);
    flags |= (nsjconf->clone_newtime ? CLONE_NEWTIME : 0);

    if (nsjconf->mode == MODE_STANDALONE_EXECVE) {
        LOG_D("unshare(flags: %s)", cloneFlagsToStr(flags).c_str());
        if (unshare(flags) == -1) {
            PLOG_F("unshare(%s)", cloneFlagsToStr(flags).c_str());
        }
        subprocNewProc(nsjconf, netfd, fd_in, fd_out, fd_err, -1);
        LOG_F("Launching new process failed");
    }

    LOG_D("Creating new process with clone flags:%s and exit_signal:SIGCHLD",
        cloneFlagsToStr(flags).c_str());

    int sv[2];
    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0, sv) == -1) {
        PLOG_E("socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC) failed");
        return -1;
    }
    int child_fd = sv[0];
    int parent_fd = sv[1];

    pid_t pid = cloneProc(flags, SIGCHLD);
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(parent_fd);
        subprocNewProc(nsjconf, netfd, fd_in, fd_out, fd_err, child_fd);
        util::writeToFd(child_fd, &kSubprocErrorChar, sizeof(kSubprocErrorChar));
        LOG_F("Launching child process failed");
    }
    close(child_fd);
    if (pid == -1) {
        auto saved_errno = errno;
        PLOG_W("clone(flags=%s) failed", cloneFlagsToStr(flags).c_str());
        close(parent_fd);
        errno = saved_errno;
        return pid;
    }
    addProc(nsjconf, pid, netfd);

    if (!initParent(nsjconf, pid, parent_fd)) {
        close(parent_fd);
        return -1;
    }

    char rcvChar;
    if (util::readFromFd(parent_fd, &rcvChar, sizeof(rcvChar)) == sizeof(rcvChar) &&
        rcvChar == kSubprocErrorChar) {
        LOG_W("Received error message from the child process before it has been executed");
        close(parent_fd);
        return -1;
    }

    close(parent_fd);
    return pid;
}
```

It means that the value of `pid` is from the `cloneProc(flags, SIGCHLD)`

After trying to fix it, I deleted and downloaded AOSP again.But It has the same problem.

I'm building in a linux environment. And I suspect that many processes running concurrently is part of the issue, but I'm not sure. So How to Fix this nsjail error?

Comment: I met the same error too, when compile AOSP source code on the CentOS 7,  Do you solve this problem now ?